# I have two projects .one project contains emp table entity .I need same table entity to access in another project using spring boot

Tags: java

I have two projects .one project contains emp table entity .I need same table entity  to access in another project using spring boot .How to do that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

Is the database shared? Or is just the data structure the same?

Two services with direct access to the SAME database doesn't sound good in the long run. You could consider having one project to make calls to the other in order to fetch data.

Comment: Hi Vitor,thank you for your reply.I have 2 databases.in one database i have emp table entity created in one spring boot project.and   i have dept table entity created in another project.I want to join emp table and dept table in second project repository.how to do that?